# feeding two iteratee with one enumerator

Tags: scala, playframework, loops

I'm very new to play framework, functional programming and Iteratee I/O, so maybe my question is very out of topic or even stupid.

I would like to upload big text files as stream to a third party and in the same time extract Meta Data about this file (based on its content, to simplify said it's a csv file).

I've already written two working body parsers: `Iteratee[Array[Byte], B]` that contains the writing logic and an `Iteratee[Array[Byte], MetaData]` that contains the MetaData extracting logic. Could you please tell me how to combine these two parsers to handle Writing and extracting content in the same time

Answer (score 4):

If you have two iteratees, `it1` and `it1`, say, you can created a "zipped" iteratee from them (`zippedIt` in the code below) that will send whatever input it receives to both iteratees, `it1` and `it2`. See the [Play Iteratee documentation of `zip`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumeratee%24).

Here's an example:

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Enumerator, Iteratee, Enumeratee}

val e = Enumerator("1", "2", "3")
val it1 = Iteratee.foreach[String](v => println("1: " + v))
val it2 = Iteratee.foreach[String](v => println("2: " + v))
val zippedIt = Enumeratee.zip(it1, it2)
e(zippedIt)
```

The console output of this small snippet is:

```
1: 1
2: 1
1: 2
2: 2
1: 3
2: 3
```